# which is right Fourier transform of $e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n)$

Tags: fourier-transform

$$\mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon})=\frac{1}{j\omega+1}$$
$$\mathcal{F}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n))=2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(\omega-2n\pi)$$
so with convolution:
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n))=\frac{1}{2\pi} \mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon})*\mathcal{F}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n))=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+j\omega+2j\pi n}$$
with different method:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(e^{-t} 1_{t > -\epsilon}\sum_{n=\infty}^\infty \delta (t-n)) &=\mathcal{F}(1+e^{-1}\delta(t-1)+e^{-2}\delta(t-2+)+e^{-3}\delta(t-3)+e^{-4}\delta(t-4)) +\cdot \\
&=1+e^{-1}e^{-j\omega}+e^{-2}e^{-j2\omega}+e^{-3}e^{-j3\omega}+e^{-4}e^{-j4\omega} +\cdot\\
&=\frac{1-e^{n(-1-j\omega)}}{1-e^{-1-j\omega}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1-j\omega}}
\end{align}

it's easily found 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+j\omega+2j\pi n}\not=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1-j\omega}}$$

So which one is the right Fourier Transform?

Comment: why do you think they are not equal ? to me they are, up to signs and constants

Comment: For sake of clarity: $j^2=-1$?

Comment: see here http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/06/05/0001/ I can prove it (and maybe generalize it to many quotient of trigonometric functions) if you want, but if you know some complex analysis and the Liouville theorem

Comment: yes. $j^2=-1$. A matlab script is running to verify if they are the same      x=1+i*1;
si=1/x;
m=400000;
for k=1:m
    
    si=si+1/(x+2*pi*1i*k)+1/(x-2*pi*1i*k);
end
si
sac=1/(1-exp(-x))   the script get different results for these two equations.

Comment: I have little knowledge about the complex analysis.  I verify these two equations with $\omega=1$. the results are indeed different.

Comment: found it : the mistake is $2 i \pi n$ not $2 \pi n$

Comment: Thanks! It's a typo.  but still the verification with Matlab is different with $\omega=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = e^z-1$. It is analytic on the whole complex plane ([entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)), its zeros are at $z = 2 i k \pi$, of order $1$, and $f'(2 i k \pi) = 1$.

Note that $g(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z-2 i k \pi}$, understood as $\lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K \frac{1}{z-2 i k \pi}$, converges absolutely for any $z \not\in \{2 i k \pi\}$, and is [meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function), hence $h(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)} -g(z)$ is meromorphic, and since it has no poles, it is entire.

Finally, $h(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)} -g(z)$ is bounded on the imaginary line, and since both $f(z), g(z) \to 0$ as $Re(z) \to \pm\infty$, we get that $h(z)$ is a bounded entire function, so that $h(z) = C$ by [the Liouville theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)). See below for the value of $C = \color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}$, and not $C=0$ as I thought.

Hence :

$$\frac{1}{f(z) } = \frac{1}{e^z-1} = -\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z-2 i k \pi}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-1-i\omega}} = \frac{-1}{f(-1-i \omega)} = -\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2 i k \pi+1+i \omega}$$

---

EDIT : the flaw was that once we know by Liouville's theorem that $h(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)} - g(z) = C$ is constant, we can compute $C$ by looking at $h(0) = \lim_{z \to 0} h(z)$ : 
$$\textstyle g(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z-2 i \pi k}+\frac{1}{z+2 i \pi k}\right) = \frac{1}{z} + 2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2+4 \pi^2 k^2}$$ so that  $$\lim_{z \to 0} g(z) - \frac{1}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0} 2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 k^2} = 0$$ and $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{f(z)} - \frac{1}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{e^z-1}-\frac{1}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z-(e^z-1)}{z(e^z-1)} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z-(z+\frac{z^2}{2}+o(z^2))}{z(z+o(z))} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ hence $$C = h(0) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{f(z)}-\frac{1}{z}-(g(z)-\frac{1}{z}) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: x=1+i*1;
si=1/x;
m=400000;
for k=1:m
    
    si=si+1/(x+2*pi*1i*k)+1/(x-2*pi*1i*k);
end
si
sac=1/(1-exp(-x))  please run the script with Matlab.

Comment: @MikeMeng : no it is your job to find the error of signs and constants, I showed you the general framework into which I can say there is nothing absurd in what you obtained.

Comment: :Thanks, I have corrected the error with constant. Just can't figure it out why the script verification is not in line with the two equations.

Comment: @MikeMeng : I would try  
z=2+i; si = 1/z;  for k=1:4000 si=si+1/(z-2* i * pi * k)+1/(z+2* i * pi * k); end si sac=1/(exp(z)-1)

Comment: Thanks! I tried. Yes verifying $z=2$ is absolutely right. However, with $z=-1-i$, the results are still confusing.  with $\omega=1$, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+j\omega+2j\pi n}=0.59-j0.42$, $\frac{1}{1-e^{-1-j\omega}}=1.06-j0.42$. Only imaginary part is the same. the real part is different. Could you please shed more light on this? I really appreciate this. this has confused me quite a long time. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeMeng : sorry I can't find the mistake :D   with a constant $-1/2$ it works better, can't find why 
z = 4+i; val = 1/(exp(z)-1)
lala = 1/z+sum(1./(z-2*i*pi*[1:K])+1./(z+2*i*pi*[1:K]));
lala-1/2

Comment: @MikeMeng : .... $C = -1/2$ was correct, see the edit. and it also means that $\lim_{Re(z) \to \infty} \sum_k \frac{1}{z - 2 i \pi k} = \lim_{Re(z) \to \infty}  g(z) = -\frac{1}{2}$, quite unobvious

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely useful to me!  Now it should follow: 
$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+j\omega+2j\pi n}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1-j\omega}}$